# Insert and resize a picture in a report

Tags: vba, image, ms-access, image-scaling

I am starting an Access database with exam questions. Almost every question will have a picture. I prefer not to save the pictures in the database to keep it small.

I want to insert these pictures in a report. The pictures must all have the same width (the width of the report), but the height must be resized according to the original aspect ratio. Some pictures are landscape and others portrait.

I am using Office 365, VBA 7.1 and Windows 10.

Comment: You can study a demo [here](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/29679/Show-pictures-directly-from-URLs-in-Access-forms-and-reports.html). Though also for downloading the pictures, it shows how to retrieve pictures from a path for both a form and a report.

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out in the end and it was so simple.

Answer (score 2):

In the end it was very simple. I am posting the solution, maybe it will save somebody else three days.

Just to explain the names.

ImageSource is a text box that contain the path of the file.

ImageFrame is an empty image that I placed on the report.

The code is placed in the OnFormat section of my GroupHeader on my Report.

The 9996 is a little smaller than the width of my report and it is in twips.

This is the code:

```
Private Sub GroupHeader3_Format(Cancel As Integer, FormatCount As Integer)
    Me![ImageFrame].Picture = Me![ImageSource]
    Me![ImageFrame].Width = 9996
    Me![ImageFrame].Height = 9996 * Me![ImageFrame].ImageHeight / Me![ImageFrame].ImageWidth
End Sub
```