# Microsoft Access 2019 Report. Automatically Resize Image Control

Tags: image, controls, report, ms-access-2016

[Insert and resize a picture in an access report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47937322/insert-and-resize-a-picture-in-an-access-report)
Solution by Ms Isabel Smit aborts at first line of code.
My Report textbox [P1] populated by query has links to *.jpg files.
But code, Me.Image46.Picture = Me.P1.Value does not work. Get error msg Run-time error '94': Invalid use of Null.
Neither does Me!Image46.Picture = Me![P1] Run-time error '13': Type mismatch
Neither does Me!Image46.Picture = Me![P1].Value
Works if Me!Image46.Picture = hard coded filename but it defeats objective of each record to link to different filename.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Updated Solution with validation:
I built your form and tested it. The only time I got it to fail was when the path to the image was invalid. Please try this:

```
Dim strFilename As String
strFilename = Me![P1].Value

If Len(Dir(strFilename)) > 0 Then
    Me![Image7].Picture = strFilename
    Me![Image7].Height = 9666 * Me![Image7].ImageHeight / Me![Image7].ImageWidth
    Me![Image7].Width = 9666
Else
    MsgBox "Image not found"
End If
```

Comment: What should change on using bang, except hiding compile errors?`Me!P1 -> Me. Controls.Item("P1").Value`won't error on missing control P1. `Me.P1.Value` raises error if missing. My guess on OPs error: P1 contains not a path but NULL. Solved by `Nz(Me.P1.Value)`

Comment: Dear Sirs, Does not work. Maybe I am not using the correct syntax. It is:

Private Sub Detail_Format(Cancel As Integer, FormatCount As Integer)
  Me![Image7].Picture = Me![P1]
  Me![Image7].Width = 9666
  Me![Image7].Height = 9666 * Me![Image7].ImageHeight / Me![Image7].ImageWidth
End Sub

P1 is a textbox contains E:\W\ATR\Investigation\Ice Detector Chart.1.png
Image gets resized when I change 9666 to say, 5000. But the Image Frame named Image7 in the Properties stays the same size. Does not shrink. Fails at first line of code.